# object with html code and method to print

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects

Can anyone help and see the problem why the code does not work. Trying to organize the code into an object. Check codepen link

```
//trying to organize this code into an object.

// var flag0 = document.getElementById("flag0");
// var flagFranskaFlaggan = `<div class="flag frankrike"><div class="part1"></div><div class="part2"></div></div>`;
// flag0.innerHTML = flagFranskaFlaggan;

//The object!
var flag = {
    draw: function() {
        var htmlId = this.htmlId;
        var cssflag = this.cssFlag;
        htmlId.innerHTML = cssFlag;
    }
}

var flag0 = Object.create(flag);
flag0.init = function(cssFlag, htmlId) {
    this.cssFlag = cssFlag;
    this.htmlId = htmlId;
}

flag0.init(`<div class="flag frankrike"><div class="part1"></div><div class="part2"></div></div>`, flag0);
flag0.draw();
```

How to insert `flag0` with `document.getElementById("flag0")` in to an object?

Comment: link to codepen https://codepen.io/alcatel1962/pen/eQqVRX/

Comment: Please insert your code to your question!

Comment: done code inserted

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to call `document.getElementById()` in the `draw()` method. And you need to pass a string as the second argument when you call `init()`.

Also, you should put the `init()` method in the object, not separate from it.

```
var flag = {
    draw: function() {
        document.getElmeentById(this.htmlId).innerHTML = this.cssFlag;
    },
    init: function(cssFlag, htmlId) {
        this.cssFlag = cssFlag;
        this.htmlId = htmlId;
    }
}

var flag0 = Object.create(flag);
flag0.init(`<div class="flag frankrike"><div class="part1"></div><div class="part2"></div></div>`, 'flag0');
flag0.draw();
```